# android.view.View cannot be cast to com.zhangxaochen.mysensor.MyView

Tags: android, custom-controls

I'm trying to add a custom view in my xml file, code is like:

```
    <View
    android:id="@+id/myView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/radioGroupSensorRate"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    class="com.zhangxaochen.mysensor.MyView" />
```

but then got runtime exceptions:

```
12-31 12:29:20.033: E/AndroidRuntime(4432): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.zhangxaochen.mysensor/com.zhangxaochen.mysensor.MyGravitySensor}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.view.View cannot be cast to com.zhangxaochen.mysensor.MyView
```

the class MyView has already been defined in my java file, I know the `<com.packageName.ClassName attrs... />` way does work to add custom widgets, but i heard some saying that the second way is like that above `<View class='com.zhangxaochen.mysensor.MyView' .../>` , i tried and then failed. could anyone tell me how to fix that? or just that saying is fake?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved~

the second way:  `<View class="packagename.ClassName" .../>`

doesn't work is just because the tag 'View' being capitalized, it *should* be in lowercase: 'view'...

Answer (score 1):

Create your Custom View in `Xml` as Follow

```
 <com.zhangxaochen.mysensor.MyView
    android:id="@+id/myView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/radioGroupSensorRate"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    />
```

Comment: thx, but maybe you didn't read all my words, I have tried the way you mentioned, and that does work, I just want to know if there is a second way or not